# Move multiple selected dataItem from one grid to another jquery

Tags: jquery, grid, kendo-ui

What I need help for is about the buttons... Two of the buttons are working (#levo and #desno)but not complitely, and the other two are not working at all.

How do I want them to work? I have two troubles:

1) When i press the button #levo it moves the selected dataItem form the first grid to the other, but if I select more than one dataItem from the first grid it moves only the first one (same thing for the other button #desno)

2) When I press the button #sitelevo I want all of the dataItem from the first grid to move to the other, with no selection (same thing for the #sitedesno)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the view  http://jsfiddle.net/WxCZf/4/

Comment: Some clarifications. When you say "move" from one grid to the other, do you mean `create` the element in the second `grid` and `delete` it from the first `grid` (meaning, meaning a delete and create into the servers)?

Comment: Yes.. Delete it from the first, and past it in the second and same for the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the problem is that `jQuery.each()` is meant to enumerate over immutable items. This means that you cannot remove items while executing the `each` since this would alter the list.

Example: Try comment the line where you remove the item from `sourcegrid` and leave the adding the item to the `destinationgrid`: you will see that the items are inserted in the destination.

```
sourcegrid.select().each(function () {
    dataItem = sourcegrid.dataItem($(this));
    // sourcegrid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
    destinationgrid.dataSource.add(dataItem);
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help that is the correct way to solve it, but I did it before you tell me (you can check the jsfiddle). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: There is only one problem now.. When I press the #sitedesno button, I want to delete the items of the second one and paste them in the first one. That works fine but, the thing is it doesn't delete them from the second one.

Comment: Don't you think that your code is too complex? Why you do not use `transport.update` and `transport.destroy` instead of all those `ajax`. Do you really need them. It's hard for me to follow you logic.

Comment: ...That was the only way I knew how to do it...What is your suggestion? I've never used transport.destroy or update. Can you show me how?